# Compare the last binary digit to 1 in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I have to check if a number is even or odd.

My strategy:

1. a number is even if ends with 0
2. a number is odd if ends with 1

How do I compare the last digit of a register value to a 0 or to a 1 ?

I tried:

```
andi $t7, $t0, 0 # where $t0 = 3 in decimal so should be 0b11
```

it doesnt work :(
Any hint?

Comment: what about `andi $t7, $t0, 1`?

Comment: shouldnt be the same thing?

Comment: Of course it won't be the same. Do you expect a result other than 0 after ANDing something with 0?

Comment: In general (I don't know MIPS assembly) you would and with a bit mask of `0x00000001` and then see if your number was 1 or 0.

Comment: if you write this as an answer I can mark this as correct.